# find the required differential of $f$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Find the required differential of $f$.

$f(x,y) = \ln(x +y)$, $d^{10}f.$

How can I find it? should I use the Leibniz rule for each of x & y, considering $f$ function as $f.1$,and if so how? or what shall I do else?

**Edit:**

$$df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy $$

what is the formula for the tenth differetial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is $d^nf(x,y)$? It is the the "full $n^{\rm th}$ derivative" of $f$ at the given point $(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2$. Usually it is written as a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$ in terms of increment variables $X$, $Y$ attached at $(x,y)$ and appears in the Taylor expansion of $f$ at $(x,y)$. The latter has the form
$$f(x+X,y+Y)=f(x,y)+df(x,y)(X,Y)+{1\over2}d^2f(x,y)(X,Y)+{1\over3!}d^3f(x,y)(X,Y)+\ldots\quad.$$
In particular one has
$$d^{10}f(x,y)(X,Y)=\sum_{j=0}^{10}{10\choose j}D_x^j D_y^{10-j}f(x,y)\>X^j\,Y^{10-j}\ ,\tag{1}$$
where I have denoted partial derivatives by $D_x$ and $D_y$.

For the function $f(x,y):=\log(x+y)$ one easily checks that
$$D_x^jD_y^{10-j}f(x,y)=-{9!\over(x+y)^{10}}\qquad(0\leq j\leq 10)\ .$$
Plugging this into $(1)$ we obtain
$$d^{10}f(x,y)(X,Y)=-{9!\over(x+y)^{10}}(X+Y)^{10}\ .\tag{2}$$
Since $dx(X,Y)=X$ and $dy(X,Y)=Y$ we can rewrite $(2)$ as
$$d^{10}f(x,y)=-{9!\over(x+y)^{10}}(dx+dy)^{10}$$
if this more along  the lines of your textbook.